# Javascript Recursive Floodfill maximum call stack exceeded

Tags: javascript, overflow, flood-fill

I'm currently making a pixel art editor and my flood fill algorithm seems to be overflowing.

```
fill(x, y, new_color, old_color) {
    var data = this.data_at(x, y);
    if(data == null) { return; }

    var is_old_color = compare_data(data, old_color)
    if(!is_old_color) { return; }

    this.render_ctx.fillStyle = rgba(new_color);
    this.render_ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
    this.fill(x, y + 1, new_color, old_color)
    this.fill(x, y - 1, new_color, old_color)
    this.fill(x + 1, y, new_color, old_color)
    this.fill(x - 1, y, new_color, old_color)
}

data_at(x, y) {
    if(state.current_selection.contains_pixel(x, y)) {
        return this.render_ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
    }
    return null;
}
```

compare_data() just checks if the current pixel's color is the same as old_color.

When using a canvas size smaller then 110*110 pixels, everything works fine. Anything bigger results in maximum call stack exceeded and only fills a portion of the canvas.

Comment: It would appear that `data_at` doesn't return `null` (or `undefined`) when `x` or `y` has gone out of bounds. So that's what you need to debug, since that's what triggers your path out of the function that doesn't recurse.

Comment: I can guarantee that data_at returns null when x or y is out of bounds.

Comment: Well, then either A) You're mistaken and it doesn't, or B) The bounds are so big you're overflowing the stack anyway. The size of the stack varies markedly by browser, but for instance on Chrome (which is relatively small) that looks like it would fail no later than about the 7,800th call: http://jsfiddle.net/af4xq968/